# pod running on different port

Tags: go, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a go application in an EKS cluster, and initially, I could successfully reach my application. Recently, I restarted the application pod. After the restart, the application is running successfully. However, when attempting to use curl on localhost:port, the request fails. Upon investigation using netstat, I discovered that the application is now connected to another application using a dynamic port. Since the application is not running on the specified port, I am unable to reach it from the service. I haven't made any changes to the codebase. What could be the issue?

Thank you.

I am trying to reach application from service

Comment: You should share your service spec and pod container ports.

Comment: Hi @MasudurRahman, with same yaml configuration ,application was being run and reachable form service. nothing changed at infra or code base end. just restarted the go application .now ,can't reach from service and can't curl localhost:port from pod .

Comment: Looks more like a problem with k8s configuration, it would be easier to solve the problem if you share your yaml.

Comment: here is my deployment file :  `apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-application
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-application
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-application
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-application
          image: acctount_number.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testapp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          imagePullPolicy: Always   
      restartPolicy: Always`

Comment: service_file: `apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testapp-service
  namespace: default
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30174
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: test-application
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}`

Comment: @MasudurRahman, With same configuration ,I can run  pod using simple nginx image and can reach successfully from service